# multitask iOS (Slide Over, Split View) on Cordova App (IntelXDK )

Tags: ios, cordova, storyboard, splitview

I have created an app in IntelXDK using cordova CLI version 6.2.0
I would like to activate the multitask for iPad, and it is impossible for me now. 
I have search for plugins but none is working. I am using the cordova-plugin-splashscreen, and I have tried to configure the Launch storyboard images (because I think is the reason that It is not working the multitask).

I have configure the config.additions.xml right that:

```
<platform name="ios">
<resource-file src="package-assets/ios/res/Launch Screen.storyboard" target="Launch Screen.storyboard" />
<splash src="package-assets/ios/res/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" />
<splash src="package-assets/ios/res/Default@2x~universal~comany.png" />
<splash src="package-assets/ios/res/Default@2x~universal~comcom.png" />
<splash src="package-assets/ios/res/Default@3x~universal~anyany.png" />
<splash src="package-assets/ios/res/Default@3x~universal~anycom.png" />
<splash src="package-assets/ios/res/Default@3x~universal~comany.png" />


<!-- below requires the splash screen plugin -->
<!-- docs: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen -->
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false"/>
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="750"/>
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false"/>
<!-- below requires the status bar plugin -->
<!-- docs: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar -->
<!-- see http://devgirl.org/2014/07/31/phonegap-developers-guid -->
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />
<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
```

As you can see, I have tried to create the spash for storyboard and the screen.storyboard

It is working now, like if I had never change anything. 
I am really lost, and I need some help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question? Is it working or not?